# $.ajax: url not "responding" when Submiting

Tags: jquery

I am (was) validating and submiting my form using:

```
$(documend).ready(function(){
//setting variables

ext_form.submit(function(){
   if(validateExt_email() & validateExt_pass()){

   var ext_email = $('#ext_email').attr('value');
   var ext_pass = $('#ext_pass').attr('value');

   $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "validation_ext.php",
      data: "ext_email="+ ext_email +"& ext_pass="+ ext_pass,
      success: function (){
         $('#content').load('p_order_ok.php');
      }
   })
      return false;
   }else
    return false;
});

//validation rules
});
```

I think it stopped working when I changed my email validation rule to:

```
//validation rules
//e-mail
function validateExt_email(){
var ext_a = $("#ext_email").val();

var emailXHR =   $.ajax({
                   type: "post",
                   url: "check_email_ext.php",
                   data: "email="+ext_a,
                   success: function(rsp){
                     //if it exists in our db
                     if(rsp == "exists"){
                       //do something
                       return true;
                     }
                     else
                     //if it's valid but not in our db
                     if(rsp == "ok" ){
                       // do something else
                       return false;
                     }
                     else
                     //if it's NOT valid
                     if(rsp == "invalid"){
                       //do something different
                       return false;
                     }   
                   }
                 }).success = function() {
}
//continuing validation
)};
```

Now is everything is validated and I hit my submit button, instead of my form posting in "validation_ext.php" is posting (as firebug shows) in "check_email_ext.php".

Any help/suggestions?

Thank you

Edit....
I gave up on this... I just used a filter and regex to validate the email. (the easy way)

Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going wrong where the `validateExt_email()` function does not return a boolean (but rather, `undefined`) because `$.ajax` fires off a request asynchronously and JavaScript doesn't wait for the `success` callback to fire. That means in this condition:

```
if(validateExt_email() & validateExt_pass()) { // always false
```

because `validateExt_email()` always evaluates to `false` (`undefined` is *falsy*).

You can refactor your solution such that the entire form submit only happens once the ajax validation functions have returned, i.e. `success` is the key, e.g.:

```
ext_form.submit(function(){

    // your email ajax checker
    var emailXHR = $.ajax({
                       type: "post",
                       url: "check_email_ext.php",
                       ...
                   }).success = function() {
                       // do next validation step
                   });
```

Comment: How do I correct this? Where exactly should I define it? (in my three success if... I am telling it when it's true or false)

Comment: My last line is a bit different .success = function() {} // do next validation }); Is it ok??? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

That's what your code says to do.

It says, whenever the form is submitted:

1. Call `validateExt_email` which makes a request to `check_email_ext.php`
2. Call `validateExt_pass`
3. If both functions return true, post to `validation_ext.php`
4. Return false

`validateExt_email` never returns any value, so your condition never passes.

Comment: ah... yes... it is called when i enter an email, or when I press submit... but even the email is correct, it never submits to validation_ext.php. And it was submiting when I wasn't posting to an external file for my email valitation.

Comment: Your `validateExt_email` function never returns any value. It just dispatches an AJAX request then ends. The AJAX request's success callback function will be called long after `validateExt_email` has already returned. Returning true/false there does not do what you think. You need to rethink your logic.

Comment: I have not said anything about your e-mail validation code (which I can't see), only your logic in processing the form submission.

Answer (score -1):

you need to change to async: false in your options.

Also your scope might not work. You see the function(e) will return true or false. That's an anonymous function. What you should do is set a value that has the same scope as your submit handler and then on the last line, return that.